# cakephp model virtualFields not working via contain

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php

I have a model called `User` which has a [Virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#virtual-fields) called `full_name`. When I access my model `User` in a find() query, I can set conditions on my Virtual field with no problem like this:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'recursive' => -1, 
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.full_name' => 'Bruce Thomas'
    )
));
```

The query above will successfully return me the data for the user called Bruce Thomas. But the problem arises when I try to use my model User through another model via the Containable behavior like this:

```
$user = $this->MyOtherModel->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array('User'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'MyOtherModel.id' => $my_other_model_id
        'User.full_name' => 'Bruce Thomas'
    )
));
```

(This example above assumes that `MyOtherModel` has a `belongsTo` relationship with my model `MyOtherModel`)

The query above gives me the following error:

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'User.full_name' in 'on clause' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 681]

Any help on how I can do this please? Thank you

Comment: Can you add/set `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in "app/config/core.php" and add `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>` in your code to check queries ?

Comment: Can you copy result wihtout conditions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the latest CakePHP documentation (for v2 and up), that is a limitation of virtual fields - [this is what it says](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields):

> The implementation of virtualFields has a few limitations. First you cannot use virtualFields on associated models for conditions, order, or fields arrays. Doing so will generally result in an SQL error as the fields are not replaced by the ORM. This is because it difficult to estimate the depth at which an associated model might be found. A common workaround for this implementation issue is to copy virtualFields from one model to another at runtime when you need to access them:

```
$this->virtualFields['name'] = $this->Author->virtualFields['name'];
```

or

```
$this->virtualFields += $this->Author->virtualFields;
```

More details here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html - if you're planning on implementing the options they suggest (which look quite alright to me) you should take a look at the "Virtual fields and model aliases" section to avoid field name clashes (i.e. if you have a field called `full_name` in two models and try issuing a query that uses both, you'll get an ambiguous field SQL error; that is avoided with aliases).

Comment: I don't get the `copy virtualFields from one model to another` part. How would you apply this to my current situation? It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Seems like you got it already, but you would do something like `$this->MyOtherModel->virtualFields['full_name'] = $this->User->virtualFields['full_name']` before issuing the 'find' command.

Answer (score 1):

In your model you have to create virtual field using below code :

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(YourModelName.first_name, " ", YourModelName.last_name)'
```

);

Now You simply need to call the below code inside your controller's condition array :

```
$condition=array($this->YourModelName->virtualFields['your_virtual_field_name'].' LIKE "%'.$YourSearchKeyword.'%"');
```